# PHPUnit Mocking functions which use Database Connection

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am new to using PHPUnit and i am trying to test function getAllTasks() which need to fetch all tasks from database. I tried everything but i am just making my code worse. So please help me to solve the problem. TaskTest.php is something i tried to make test but it dont works. And sure if there are better ways to do something, i like to learn new stuff too. Here is my code:

EDIT: I changed code for TaskTest.php and i managed to get test pass. Can someone please tell me if this is good way to test this function, or there are better ways? Thanks!

Task.php

```
<?php

  require_once 'Database.php';

  class Task {
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function getAllTasks() {
      $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tasks');
      $results = $this->db->resultSet();

      return $results;
    }
}
```

Database.php

```
<?php
  class Database {

    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $pass = '123456';
    private $dbname = 'todolist';

    private $dbh;
    private $stmt;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
      // Set DSN
      $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
      $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
      );

        // Create PDO instance
      try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
      } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        echo $this->error;
      }
    }

public function query($sql){
      $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
      $this->execute();
    }

public function execute(){
      return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultSet(){
      $this->execute();
      return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
}
```

TaskTest.php

```
<?php
require_once './src/Task.php';
require_once './src/Database.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

  class TaskTest extends TestCase {

    public function testGetAllTasks() {

      $table = array(
        array(
          'task_id' => '1',
          'task_desc' => 'Task One Test'
        ),
        array(
          'task_id' => '2',
          'task_desc' => 'Task Two Test'
        )
      );

      $dbase = $this->getMockBuilder('Database')
        ->getMock();

      $dbase->method('resultSet')
          ->will($this->returnValue($table));

      $expectedResult = [
                          'task_id' => '1',
                          'task_desc' => 'Task One Test',
                        ];

      $task = new Task();
      $actualResult =  $task->getAllTasks();

      $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $actualResult[0]);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be glad to help, especially with testing! But... What exactly is the problem..?

Comment: @Loek Problem is when i run test it says:
Expectation failed for method name is equal to "query" when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the mock to the `Task` class constructor, but it doesn't do anything with it.

`$task = new Task($resultSetMock);`

Updated the code so that it will be used:

```
class Task {
    private $db;

    public function __construct( ?Database $db = null ) {
        // set the db if none is provided
        if( is_null($db) )
        {
            $db = new Database;
        }

        $this->db = $db;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I used your code, but there is another problem now:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Task::__construct(),

Comment: @iposave correct, I forgot the initial value (`= null`). The `?` states that the variable can be `null` OR from the type `Database`. Updated the answer.

Comment: i managed to get test passed and i changed the code in question. Is it the good way to test getAllTasks() function?

Comment: @iposave Good to hear that the code works. Please accept the answer because this fixed your main issue. The other question regarding testing; if you want to check if the `getAllTasks()` handles the outcome of the db correctly then yes. If you want to check if the database is touched then you can use the `->expects( $this->once() )` to the mock and ditch te equal assertion. Keep reading into unit testing about when to stub and when to mock.

Comment: WHen i use expects($this->once()) this error happens: Expectation failed for method name is equal to "resultSet" when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Comment: `$dbase->expects( $this->once() )->method('resultSet')->will($this->returnValue($table));` For more info how to use you can read https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/test-doubles.html and then ask a new question on SO if you need more help after that. Can't help you more on this because it's not the original question. See SO guide lines. Good luck

Comment: Yes i tried like this i know how to add expects, but it still gives the same error.