# Method Mocking in PHPUnit 9.5.2

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I'm new to mocking in PHP, and it seems I misunderstand something, as I can not get the basics working:

```
class Klass
{
    public function a(): string
    {
        return 'a';
    }
}

class MockTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    function testA(): void
    {
        $klass = new Klass();

        $this->assertEquals('a', $klass->a());
    }

    function testMockA()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Klass::class)->getMock();

        $mock->method('a')->willReturn('foo');

        $klass = new Klass();

        $this->assertSame('foo', $klass->a());
    }
}
```

The test testMockA fails because $klass->a() still returns 'a'. The mock seems to do nothing?

I based this on [PHPUnit Mocking functions which use Database Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120069/phpunit-mocking-functions-which-use-database-connection), where I used the contents on TaskTest.php: that's what I want in the end, to mock my Database class to not do actual queries, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$mock->a()` and not `$klass->a()`. In fact, you should not even create `$klass`.

Comment: I don't see what good it does meto create a mock class and use that? I can do the same bij extending it.
Is what I try to do not possible in PHP? Because what I'm trying to do is test the output of REST endpoints without making them unnecessailry slow by contacting the database.

Comment: @RuudvanderLinden, your example is too minimal to see your problem clearly. When you want to mock the DB access, you need two classes typically, one that represents the DB connection and one "worker". You could then mock the DB class and use that mock for your worker during testing. You get the idea?